# 'View Workflow Reports' link missing in newly migrated Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, migration

Original Sp2007 site has the link to View Workflow Reports. Migrated to SP2013 and now I cannot see the link even though the workflows are working correctly.
I also tried activating the Reporting feature at site collection level but to no avail.

What else do I have to do to view the workflow reports in Sharepoint 2013?